# Are there docs for the Juju bundle file format?

Tags: juju

I would like to create Juju bundles without using the GUI. Is there documentation for the bundle configuration file format, or even just a schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The bundles are actually part of the juju-deployer tool. You can find more information about the tool and the bundle config file format here:

- http://pythonhosted.org/juju-deployer/config.html

Here's a bunch of bundles if you want to see existing ones:

- https://jujucharms.com/solutions?type=bundle

sources:

- [Is it possible to deploy multiple charms in one click?](https://askubuntu.com/a/584733/172367)
- [Is it possible to deploy bundles to specific machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592177/is-it-possible-to-deploy-to-specific-machine-with-bundle)